# can anybody help me. I am stuck at this step where Django is not able to show requested page

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am doing this Django project and I am stuck at this. I have created a new url path which will return the value which will be given after movies/__ in url.
here is my code:
note: movie is one the app in my application

movies/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
   path("", views.index, name="movie_index"),
   path("< movie_id >", views.detail, name="movie_detail")
]
```

movies/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import movie
def index(request):
    movies = movie.objects.all()
    return render(request, "movies/index.html", {"movies": movies})


def detail(request, movie_id):
       return HttpResponse(movie_id)
```

views.py in root folder

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('movies/', include('movies.urls'))
]
```

my error :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETgoh.png)

I am using Django 2.1 and python 3.8
thanks in advance.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
path("<int:movie_id>", views.detail, name="movie_detail")
```

instead of

```
path("< movie_id >", views.detail, name="movie_detail")
```

Comment: thank u so much...the spaces was the core problem. I never thought that spaces would play such a important role